# Missing template on render

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, afnetworking

My error:

```
 ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template api/magic_photos/create, api/base/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :rabl]}. Searched in:
2014-08-15T16:15:45.610918+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-08-15T16:15:45.610928+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2014-08-15T16:15:45.610929+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
```

Controller code:

```
  if photo.save
    magic_photo = photo.magic_photos.build( magic: magic )
    magic_photo.save
    render json: photo.json_hash(magic, current_user)
  else
    render status: 500
  end
```

A CURL of

curl -X POST -F "photo=@/path/path.jpg;type=image/jpg" "http://magic-photo-app.herokuapp.com/api/magics/44/photosdescription=SomeDescription123&auth_token=DQWCqasiqVqYZxNp3W1y"

works and returns the JSON.

When I make this request, I get a 500 and the Missing Template error

```
description = [description stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"api/magics/%@/photos?description=%@&auth_token=%@", magic.identifier, description, [NSUserDefaults authToken]];

NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [CURequestHelpers baseURL], path];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.25f);
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[CURequestHelpers baseURL]];

NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:@{} constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    NSString *fileName = @"image.jpg";
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:fileName mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];


[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [self.delegate pictureUploadProxyUploadDidSucceed:self];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"UPLOAD ERROR RESPONSE: %@", operation.responseString);
    NSLog(@"UPLOAD ERROR: %@", error);
    [self.delegate pictureUploadProxyUploadDidFail:self];
}];

NSOperationQueue *q = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]; [q addOperation:operation];
```

Why does my CURL succeed where my HTTP POST in Obj-c fail?

ROUTES:

```
  namespace :api do
    resources :magics, only: [:index, :show, :create, :album] do
      resources :photos, only: [:index, :show, :create], controller: 'magic_photos'
```

EDIT:

The actual error showing up is "image can't be blank".

Doh. I had the parameter wrong. Just needed to ask someone to look it over..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your validations, something is preventing your model from being saved and it goes into your `else` statement.

The error messages should tell you what the problem is.

You might also have a problem with the:

```
render status: 500
```

It's what's causing confusion and the `MissingTemplate` error, you're missing the template parameter

```
render :template => "public/500.html", :status => 500
```

**EDIT quantumpotato**

Turns out the problem was that the image sent from the Obj-C code was sent using the `image` query parameter instead of `photo`.

Comment: There is API in the curl, sorry I forgot it. Was typing manually

Comment: Ok! And what about your MagicPhoto model, any validations happening there?

Comment: I was uploading with "image" since that's the name of the model, but the param used is "photo". If you want to change your answer to this I'll accept & reward bounty. Since you brought up validations :)

Comment: Done. Also added some remarks about your MissingTemplate problem.